What are the frequencies of MIDI notes C4 / C3 = 60 Roland vs Yamaha
this question which had marked mine for duplicate, has nothing to do with frequencies, at least in the answers. the image shows frequencies but I'm not sure what that means which is why:
I am confused with what changes between the Roland and Yamaha systems. There's a few parts to this question but they're closely related.
I think the main question is, what are the similarities and differences when switching between the Roland and Yamaha systems?
is middle C always the same frequency so the Roland C4 is the same frequency as the Yamaha C3? ie frequency = middle c = roland c4 = yamaha c3?
the midi note value 60 represents roland c4 and yamaha c3 so does that mean its frequency is different?
What is actually different out of these affected elements?

middle C (what is the frequency of middle C?)
midi note value (0-127?)
frequency
C3/C4 when using roland or yamaha standard


What exactly are these Roland and Yamaha systems?

Thanks, that explains. I've had a Yamaha digital piano and read the manual, and they're not exactly advertising the weirdness.

Roland i believe was the first who made C4 as middle C, then some american standard used C3 as middle C and yamaha did the same. so it's known as Roland vs Yamaha tuning.

It's clearly visible in the diagram in the duplicate question: middle C = C4 = 261.6 Hz = midi note #60

And as explained in the answer there Yamaha calls this note C3.

why can't i wrap my head around it.. seems so simple, I think I get it now, middle C = 261.6Hz = midi#60... so the only thing that changes between the two systems is the octave number. the keys would be in the same position physically and they would trigger the same frequency and midi note number... but not the PitchClass/Octave notation which I have no idea what that's used for now.. are the notes the same on a score or staff?

I can't even think how I could test it, sorry peoples, thanks for chippin in while i chip away my brain again
